# Query and Assignment in a Single Step

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that has 3 properties:

```
class Three
{
   int ID { get; set ;}
   string Name { get; set; }
   double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a linq query that returns a `Queryable<Three>` but only ID and Name are defined within the table.

```
var three = from t in db.Threes
            select t;

three = { {ID=1, Name="A", Value=0},{ID=2, Name="B", Value=0},...}
```

So Value is not defined within the db.Threes table so it defaults to 0 as doubles do. I then iterate over each item in `var three` to set Value based upon another table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < three.Count(); i++)
{
   three[i].Value = (from v in db.Values
                     where v.ThreeID = i.ID
                     select v.Value).First();
}

return three;
```

The `Queryable<Three>` `three` now contains definitions for .Value:

```
three = { {ID=1, Name="A", Value=99},{ID=2, Name="B", Value=100},...}
```

The key thing that I'm trying to do is to still return a `Queryable<Three>`, but to also set the Value property.

Is there a better way to do this instead of using a for loop?

I'd like to be able to extend this to any class with a Value property that is assigned from another table; suppose I have a class Four:

```
class Four
{
   int ID {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
   DateTime Date {get; set;}
   double Value {get; set;}
}
```

The first query would populate with ID, Name and Date and I still want to be able to assign Value.  I feel like there is a better way to do this with linq that I just can't come up with.

**Edit:** suppose I'm calling `db.GetTable<T>` and Three and Four are really generic arguments that implement a `.Value` interface. I can't explicitly instantiate a generic type because I would have to hard code the properties.

Comment: Please don't put tags like "C# LINQ" into your titles. We have tags for that, and they do a better job of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647#groupjoin). You are assigning values from another table whose id is the same as the `Three` table.

You can build back a `Three` object like this:

```
var three = from t in db.Threes
            join v in db.Values on t.ID equals v.ThreeID
            select new Three{
                            ID = t.ID, 
                            Name = t.Name,
                            Value = v.Value 
                         };
```

What you were doing before by looping, that is a performance hit. What happens is that you called to the database to loop it, then for each loop, you make another call back to the database. If your tables are linked by those Ids, then using this code makes 1 single database call and no in memory looping.

Comment: What if `Three` is really a generic type?  I can't call a constructor inside the linq query?  That's I guess what I was trying to get at with the Four part at the end.  I should have been more clear.

Comment: No, you can't call a constructor inside a linq statement

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple join, assuming you have some common key?

```
var things = from t in db.Threes
             join v in db.Values on t.SomeId equals v.SomeId
             select new Three { ID = t.ID, 
                                Name = t.Name,
                                Value = v.Value 
                              };
```